# Excel VBA Function to hide/unhide Rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new to VBA/Macro.  I need some help figuring how to hide/unhide rows given my scenario.  This is my table:

See Table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5rj1.png)

What I would like to do is:

1) Create a function (or sub) with three arguments:

- FlagRange:  flagRange or C1:C9
- hideAction: True/False
- Flag: This is one of the flag value

Example:  Hide_Unhide(flagRange, True, "P")

2) This function will hide all the row(s) based on the Flag that is passed into the argument.

Any suggestions and samples are appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you post your existing code and tell us where the problem is exactly?

Comment: when should a row be hidden and when should it not be? You need to explain what your flag is...

Comment: @urdearboy - If I call the function with Flag="P", for example, it will only hid rows with "P" in column-C.  The rest should remain visible or un-hidden.  The flags (x, y, p etc.) are arbitrary/pre-define value to identify the different row category.  Hope this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options. The second sub is going to be faster as it will hide all the rows at once rather many possible iterations of hiding rows. The larger the # of rows to be hidden, the more you will notice the time saved by using the `Union` approach

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideMe(FlagRange As Range, Flag As String)

FlagRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Dim FlagCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each FlagCell In FlagRange
        FlagCell.EntireRow.Hidden = FlagCell = Flag 'Rows get hidden here
    Next FlagCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideMeUnion(FlagRange As Range, Flag As String)

FlagRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Dim FlagCell As Range, HideMe As Range

For Each FlagCell In FlagRange
    If FlagCell = Flag Then
        If HideMe Is Nothing Then
            Set HideMe = FlagCell
        Else
            Set HideMe = Union(HideMe, FlagCell)
        End If
    End If
Next FlagCell

'rows gettin hidden here all at once
If Not HideMe Is Nothing Then HideMe.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @urdearboy.  I got "Compile error: Next without For" using the Union option.

Comment: Wow!  That worked much better @urdearboy.  The only thing I noticed now is that I have cells in Column-C that are blanked.  This code also hide all those.  I would like those blank cell rows to be untouched.  Possible?

Comment: Okay.  Mike mistake.  Update code work.  What I did was I changed "FlagCell = Flag" to "FlagCell <> Flag" to try an reverse result.  This cause the blanked cell rows to be hidden.  I was hope I can leave the blank cells untouched.

Comment: Again, thanks @urdearboy.  Per my last comment, what can I do if I want to leave the blank cells alone?

Comment: If you are trying the reverse test you will need to use `If FlagCell <> "" And FlagCell <> Flag Then`, which reads as, *if cell is not blank and not equal to flag string then...*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private sub Hide_Unhide(FlagRange as Range, Hide as Boolean, FlagValue as String)
Dim c as Variant
    For Each c in FlagRange
           c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next c
    For Each c in FlagRange
        If c.Value2 = FlagValue Then
           c.EntireRow.Hidden = Hide
        End IF
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution to to hide/unhide rows:

```
Function Hide_Unhide(flagRange As Range, hideAction As Boolean, Flag As String)
        For Each Row In flagRange.Rows
            If Row.Cells(3) = Flag Then
                Row.EntireRow.Hidden = hideAction
            End If
        Next Row
End Function
```